# How to create an array of 20 random bytes?

Tags: java, arrays, random

How can I create an array of 20 random bytes in Java?

Answer (score 317, accepted):

Try the [`Random.nextBytes`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextBytes(byte[])) method:

```
byte[] b = new byte[20];
new Random().nextBytes(b);
```

Comment: worth adding a note that this is not crypto-safe. see [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34912596/1220560) if you need such.

Answer (score 66):

If you want a cryptographically strong random number generator (also thread safe) without using a third party API, you can use `SecureRandom`.

Java 8 (more secure than previous versions):

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[20];
SecureRandom.getInstanceStrong().nextBytes(bytes);
```

Java 6 & 7:

```
SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
byte[] bytes = new byte[20];
random.nextBytes(bytes);
```

Answer (score 26):

If you are already using Apache Commons Lang, the  [`RandomUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/RandomUtils.html)  makes this a one-liner:

```
byte[] randomBytes = RandomUtils.nextBytes(20);
```

Note: this does not produce cryptographically-secure bytes.

Comment: After doing some digging, RandomUtils uses Math.random() under the hood, not SecureRandom. Just wanted to make this explicit.

Comment: This method doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: @MartijnHiemstra It does exist: https://github.com/apache/commons-lang/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/lang3/RandomUtils.java#L72

Comment: @DuncanJones I am using Spring boot 2 that uses Commons lang 3.7 and it has been removed. Viewing the source code shows that it has been commented out. So I wouldn't trust this code since an upgrade might render your code uncompilable.

Comment: @MartijnHiemstra I checked the latest docs at:
https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/index.html
and also the docs for version 3.7 at :
https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.7/org/apache/commons/lang3/RandomUtils.html

They both seem to have the nextBytes method. Perhaps spring boot is not importing the correct libraries ?

Answer (score 8):

Java 7 introduced [ThreadLocalRandom](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html) which is ***isolated to the current thread***.

This is an another rendition of [maerics's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5683221/330457).

```java
final byte[] bytes = new byte[20];
ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextBytes(bytes);
```

Comment: Maybe some parentheses too many after the word `ThreadLocalRandom` ? Better: `ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextBytes(bytes);`

Answer (score 4):

Create a **Random** object with a seed and get the array random by doing:

```
public static final int ARRAY_LENGTH = 20;

byte[] byteArray = new byte[ARRAY_LENGTH];
new Random(System.currentTimeMillis()).nextBytes(byteArray);
// get fisrt element
System.out.println("Random byte: " + byteArray[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

For those wanting a more secure way to create a random byte array, yes the most secure way is:

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[20];
SecureRandom.getInstanceStrong().nextBytes(bytes);
```

BUT your threads might block if there is not enough randomness available on the machine, depending on your OS. The following solution will not block:

```
SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
byte[] bytes = new byte[20];
random.nextBytes(bytes);
```

This is because the first example uses `/dev/random` and will block while waiting for more randomness (generated by a mouse/keyboard and other sources). The second example uses `/dev/urandom` which will not block.

Comment: You should only use this example if requirements demand timeliness over correctness, or in this case true randomness. /dev/urandom will not block if it can't create true randomness and will do the best it can. /dev/random will block until randomness is guaranteed.